# DLLImport when c++ function involves a callback containing a struct

Tags: c#, struct, callback, interop

We have a c++ function

`IMPEXP int startGettingData(LPCWSTR port, ClubConfig* pClubConfig, void (__stdcall *onSwingCalculated)(CalculationResult* pResult));`

The Calculation result is a struct in c++

```
typedef struct stCalculationResult
{
BOOL    isLeftHanded;   
double  lie;            
double  open;           
double  loft;           
double  attack;         
double  startLie;       
double  startOpen;      
double  startLoft;      
double  faceToPath;     
double  clubPath;       
double  startLean;      
double  endLean;        
double  startTime;      
double  stopTime;       
double  tempo;          
double  clubHeadSpeed;
int32_t numberOfPositions;  
int32_t vectorLength;
int32_t matrixLength;
int32_t impact;             
int32_t tobs;               
int32_t halfway;            
int32_t quarterway;         
int32_t three_quarterway;   
int32_t rawDataLength;      
double* CorrPositions;     
double* Orientations;       
double* HVelocities;        
double* HAngularVelocities;
int32_t* rawData;
} CalculationResult;
```

I am trying to figure out how to call this function in c#  This is what I have so far

```
[DllImport("my.dll")]
static extern Int32 startGettingData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string port, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] ClubConfig pClubConfig, onSwingCalculate d);
```

and the delegate

```
public delegate void onSwingCalculate(IntPtr data);
```

and the struct

```
public struct CalculationResult
{
    public bool isLeftHanded;       
    public double lie;             
    public double open;         
    public double loft;         
    public double attack;           
    public double startLie; 
    public double startOpen;
    public double startLoft;
    public double faceToPath;
    public double clubPath; 
    public double startLean;
    public double endLean;  
    public double startTime;
    public double stopTime; 
    public double tempo;    
    public double clubHeadSpeed;

    public Int32 numberOfPositions;
    public Int32 vectorLength;
    public Int32 matrixLength;
    public Int32 impact;                
    public Int32 tobs;              
    public Int32 halfway;           
    public Int32 quarterway;            
    public Int32 three_quarterway;  
    public Int32 rawDataLength;      
    public IntPtr CorrPositions;     
    public IntPtr Orientations;      
    public IntPtr HVelocities;        
    public IntPtr HAngularVelocities;
    public IntPtr rawData;            
}
```

and finally the actual callback function

```
void SwingCalculate(IntPtr data)
{
    CalculationResult result = new CalculationResult();
    result = (CalculationResult)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data, typeof(CalculationResult));
    Debug.Log("Clubhead speed: " +result.clubHeadSpeed);
}
```

Unfortunatly when the callback function receives data it disconnects.

Comment: If it's a C++ function then it will be name-mangled... are you sure it's not a C function?  Also note that `BOOL` is a typedef for `int` on Windows, so you need to pick a compatible C# type.  (The `bool` type is not compatible.)  You may also need `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` on the struct.

Comment: YEs Sorry EXTERN C is declared on the function.  The call to startGettingData works until data is recieved through the callback